# Query working on SQL*Plus but not in jdbc program

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, exception, oracle11g

I executed a query on sqlplus (Oracle 11g)

```
select Bookdetails.TITLE,Bookdetails.PRICE
from bookdetails
inner join orderdetails
ON BOOKDETAILS.BOOKID=ORDERDETAILS.BOOKID
Where Orderdetails.username ='Divya.grg';
```

I got this output:

```
TITLE                                                             PRICE
------------------------------------------------------------ ----------
mastering c++                                                     876.2
construction material reference book 2nd edition                    332
let us c++                                                          793
```

But when I did the same query on a JDBC program:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select Bookdetails.TITLE,Bookdetails.PRICE"
  +"from bookdetails"
  +"inner join orderdetails"
  +"ON BOOKDETAILS.BOOKID=ORDERDETAILS.BOOKID"
  +"Where Orderdetails.username ='"+username+"'");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
```

I am getting this exception:

```
>java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Now why would this happen? If sqlplus is executing this without any problem then why would the exception be thrown in program?

Comment: It's a typo. @rgettman is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place spaces at the beginnings of your lines you're concatenating to create your query in Java, or else the lines you're concatenating will run the query together as:

```
select Bookdetails.TITLE,Bookdetails.PRICEfrom bookdetailsinner join orderdetails...
```

when you want

```
select Bookdetails.TITLE,Bookdetails.PRICE from bookdetails inner join orderdetails...
```